# Why JS doesn't execute if it it's in between form tags?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;

function init() { //wait for load and watch for click
    var button = document.getElementById("searchbutton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick(e) { //get user input and go to a new url
    var textinput = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    var searchterm = textinput.value;
    window.location.assign("http://google.com/example/" + searchterm)
}
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searchinput">  
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Ara" id="searchbutton">
```

In this code block, it gets user input and go to a new url with user input.

if I move last line into form element it doesn't working.
But I'm using id to find elements.

Comment: if submit button is part of form, it helps form in submission and page will be refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Ara" id="searchbutton">
```

use this ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button))

```
<button type="button" id="searchbutton">Ara</button>
```

Your button works as a form submit button, so instead of just executing your JavaScript, it also tries to submit the form, which points back to the script itself. By using `<button type="button">` you define a mere button without any submitting functionality.

Besides: If you don't need the surrounding `<form>` element, why not drop it out of the code?

Comment: Thanks for answer and suggestions. I'm new at coding.

Answer (score 4):

you can specify the OnSubmit as explained in the below code fragment, and it will work.

```
<form method="GET" onsubmit="handleButtonClick(event)"> 
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searchinput">  
</form>

function handleButtonClick(e) { 

    var textinput = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    var searchterm = textinput.value;
    window.location.assign("http://google.com/example/" + searchterm)
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why return false is there? (I'm new at coding.)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it is because your `submit` button is submitting the form.

Add `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` to your code.

```
function handleButtonClick(e) { //get user input and go to a new url
    e.preventDefault();
    var textinput = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    var searchterm = textinput.value;
    window.location.assign("http://google.com/example/" + searchterm)
    return false;
}
```

This should stop the form from submitting cross browser.

Comment: @Alex yeah but I believe ( at the back of my mind somewhere ) that old old old browsers (if you care about them) do not have a `preventDefault()` method, so this is a "Catch All" bit of code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use it an Opera extension. This is a bit hard way. I'll prefer @Sirko's answer.

Comment: @Imrahil Sirko's answer maybe be easier for you to implement, however what happens when a user has javascript turned off? I know this is going to be a very small percentage, but your button is then not going to do anything. If you implement my code, then your form will still submit and you can handle this.

Comment: I appreciate for explanation. I'm coding an Opera extension so user will have to open javascript. Also why did you put return false? What's it's purpose?